# How to get data in post axios response php next.js?

Tags: javascript, axios

this is the axios post response I tried to get the text of error in the response of the post axios
I start with
(Res.request.response)
It give object in object in object
When I went to add `.data` its became `undefined`.

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
  config: {url: "https/v1/user/login", method: "post", data: "{"email":"09@gmail.com","password":"it"}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
  data: {success: true, statusCode: 200, data: {…}}
  headers: {access-control-allow-headers: "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token", access-control-allow-methods: "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT", access-control-allow-origin: "*", access-control-max-age: "1000", connection: "keep-alive", …}
  request: XMLHttpRequest
  onabort: ƒ ()
  onerror: ƒ ()
  onload: null
  onloadend: null
  onloadstart: null
  onprogress: null
  onreadystatechange: ƒ ()
  ontimeout: ƒ ()
  readyState: 4
  response: "{"success":true,"statusCode":200,"data":{"errors":{"password":["Incorrect email or password"]}}}"
  responseText: "{"success":true,"statusCode":200,"data":{"errors":{"password":["Incorrect email or password"]}}}"
  responseType: ""
  responseURL: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.w.com/v1/user/login"
  responseXML: null
  status: 200
  statusText: "OK"
  timeout: 0
  upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}
  withCredentials: false
  __proto__: XMLHttpRequest
  status: 200
  statusText: "OK"
```

when I try console.log(Res.request.response)
this is the result

`{"success":true,"statusCode":200,"data":{"errors":{"password":["Incorrect email or password"]}}}`

How can I iterate  to get this result: `Incorrect email or password`

Comment: Put what you tried

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: It's better to use axios interceptors and use the catch statement in try-catch operator.

Comment: i do not want to catch the error i need just this value "Incorrect email or password"

Comment: `Res.request.response.data.errors.password[0]`

Comment: its give me undefined

Comment: I thing its need (.json) some where but i cant handle it

Comment: It seem json data how can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you are skipping a `data` here.

Try `Res.request.response.data.data.errors.password.join('\n')`

That .join('\n') is optional. You can replace it with `...password[0]`.

---

If you'd like to learn a bit, this is how I approach exploring this object. It's kind of a skillset in and of itself.

Let's give it a shot.

From what you printed above (`Res.request.response`), I did the following:

```
let respData = JSON.parse('{"success":true,"statusCode":200,"data":{"errors":{"password":["Incorrect email or password"]}}}');

console.log(respData.data.errors.password.join('\n'));
// logs: "Incorrect email or password"
```

That worked.

Notice, console.log surrounds the data with quotes indicating it's type string.

Looking at `Res.request.data`, there are no quotes around it. It looks like an object. Guessing axios already called JSON.parse on the value.

Since `Res.request.response` and `Res.request.data` are at the same level in the object, it would appear that `Res.request.data === {success: true, statusCode: 200, data: {…}}`.

To get at the data you're after, you'd need to call `Res.request.data.data` to access that part of the response.

In other words:

```
let responseData = Res.request.data;
responseData.success === true
let errors = responseData.data.errors
let firstPasswordError = errors.password[0]
```

If that doesn't help, let me know.